# Photoshop Adjust Paragraph Box to Content

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, paragraph

I was wondering if there's a way to adjust a paragraph text box to it's content just like inDesign.

I hate how sometimes I have to create big paragraph boxes and end up selecting them later on because there's too much leftover space. I know I can resize them manually, but the snapping to the last line isn't as reliable as in inDesign and it would be just easier if there was a way to adjust it automatically.

**Is there a setting to automatically resize a textbox to it's contents? Alternatively, can I make this into an Action?**

Comment: No and yes. There is no such feature, but you can the similar result by first converting it `Type > Convert to point text` and then back to `Type > Convert to paragraph text`... and yes, you can make an action out of it. This isn't the most reliable method though. It can leave some white space within the frame and it will delete any text outside of the text frame.

Comment: @joonas could you leave that as an answer